# Some laptop keyboard keys only function after reseating ribbon; is this an issue w/ the keyboard or MB? How can I find out?

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

Last night my enter, delete, arrow, and a couple of other keys ceased functioning. I opened the laptop and reseated the ribbon—and the keys began working again. Shortly after, they stopped once more. While reseating works temporarily, it seems like this will inevitably lead to the keys just not working.

Is this a keyboard ribbon problem (that I can solve by ordering a replacement keyboard) or is there something worse going on? Is there any means of finding out? I believe it's certainly hardware related, because these keys don't work on the BIOS menus (as opposed to just the OS).

(I'm running Arch Linux on a Sager NP7276 laptop, if this is relevant)

Comment: I would try a (chemical) contact cleaner (e.g. poly phenyl ether).  That has solved problems for me with weak battery contacts, noisy audio plugs/jacks, and intermittent data connections.